# Moving a field inside an array

Tags: mongodb

I have an array containing a subdocument. I need to take the fields inside this subdocument to outside the subdocument. The document is something like this.

```
field1: "abc"
field2: "dsf"
field3: {

    allowed-type: [
               field4: "32"
}
```

I need to take field 4 outside of the array allowed-type and put it under field3. I have tried the following

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach( function (doc) {   
    doc.field3.field4 = 'doc.field3.allowed-type.field4';
db.collection.save(doc);  });
```

The problem is that the array allowed-type contains a hyphen so I can't refer to it without using double quotes. But when i use double quotes field4 will be assigned 'doc.field3.allowed-type.field4' as a string rather than taking the value from doc.field3.allowed-type.field4.

Comment: how about `= doc.field3['allowed-type'].field4`?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation is your solution. You will first have to unwind your document, this will basically flatten the document and take "32" out of the array. You will then need to take the returned result and project the "field4" value to a new field, which is a document under "field3". pretty() is only to present the result in a readable format.

```
db.fields.aggregate(
   {$unwind:"$field3.allowed-type.field4"}, 
   {$project: 
       {field1:1, 
        field2:1, 
        field3: 
           {field4: "$field3.allowed-type.field4"
}} }).pretty();
```